# Debugging CakePHP 2.4 app with xdebug and netbeans does not work

Tags: php, cakephp, netbeans, xdebug

I am trying to debug a CakePHP 2.4 app. My setup is a WAMP server with PHP 5.3.13 and xDebug 2.2.5. I am using NetBeans 8.0

This is my php.ini settings:

```
    zend_extension = c:\wamp\bin\php\php5.3.13\ext\php_xdebug-2.2.5-5.3-vc9.dll

    [xdebug]
    xdebug.remote_enable = on
    xdebug.remote_handler=dbgp
    xdebug.remote_host=127.0.0.1
    xdebug.remote_port=9000
    xdebug.idekey="netbeans-xdebug"
    xdebug.remote_autostart=on
    xdebug.profiler_enable = on
    xdebug.profiler_enable_trigger = on
```

When I start a debug session on NetBeans it says in status bar `netbeans-xdebug running`. And also my `phpinfo()` show that xDebug is loaded, but the website I try to debug is blank white and loading takes forever with no result.

I am loading index.php and it is rewrited by xDebug as:

```
    http://localhost/webakis3dev/index.php?XDEBUG_SESSION_START=netbeans-xdebug
```

I think it has something to do with XDEBUG_SESSION_START=netbeans-xdebug part. 
Typically i would use:

```
    http://localhost/webakis3dev/index.php to access index.php.
```

Comment: No need to help, I found what problem was on NetBeans, i needed to press continue(F5) on each request for it to load.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No need to help, I found what problem was on NetBeans, i needed to press continue(F5) on each request for it to load.

In order to avoid this behavour, I needed to disable 'Stop at first line' checkbox in debugging options window of NetBeans